# 2D color plot when one of the dimensions has a single value

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to make a 2-D color plot with a script that formerly was dealing with a rectangle of data. However, I now need to use it to work with only a single point on the x axis having data.

What I've got is:

```
self.fig = plt.figure('Title', (10.,10.))
ax=plt.subplot(111)
im=ax.imshow(color_array,interpolation='none',extent=[100,100,50,150],aspect=0.15)
# setting labels, climate, color bar, saving image, etc..
```

I'm sure what's causing the issue is the `extent = [100,100`, I'm just not exactly sure how to write the code differently in order for the plot to show up as something other than a narrow vertical rectangle with nothing inside.

The color array is typically a 2-d array of numbers, but in this limited case, it is essentially a 1-d array. What happens is, there are three 2-d arrays, all the same dimensions, and two of them make up the x and y axes, and the third (the color array) determines the coloring of the field. Right now it they look (simplified) like this:

y-axis: `[[90,100,110,120]]`

x-axis: `[[100,100,100,100]]`

color: `[[10,11,13,14]]`

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: What's the shape the `color_array`?  You can always add extra dimensions if you need to (e.g. `np.atleast_2d`, `np.atleast_3d`, `data[None,None,:]`, etc).  Also, it would help immensely if you could include the traceback for the error you're getting.  Setting the extent the way you have it will give a warning, but no error.

Comment: @JoeKington I apologize, my question was a little unclear. I'm not receiving an error, the plots are still being created, they're just being created as horizontal rectangles without any color in the middle. Basically, the issue is that since the horizontal axis only has one parameter, it's being squashed so that the color part of the plot is, in a sense, 'infinitesimally small.' I will make the appropriate edit to the question regarding the other information you asked for, as well as an image of what the plots look like now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very simple. All that's required is a simple adjustment to the extent. Basically, just make sure the two values on the same axes have a distance of larger than 0 between them.

```
im=ax.imshow(color_array,interpolation='none',extent[100-1,100+1,50,150],aspect=0.15)
```

I used a value of 1 to separate the above, but really, any number will work (you can also scale it to the changing dimensions of your plots if you like it to be consistent).

I used an `if` statement to make sure that this only occurs in situations where the first index of the axis array is equal to the last index.